# ORTools / Python : How to keep track of the amount of some variables in the solve process?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, cp-sat

First, I want to precise I'm not a pro dev. I have some really basics knowledge, and this is my first real coding Project. ( and i guess i didnt choose the easiest one ) This is a Python(3) project.

I wanted to create a tool for a famous football video games.

Currently I managed (with some help) to get the "main" purpose working : you import some players and their attribute into your roster ( I'm working with database ), and the Solver find you the best 11 players possible for your starting team depending of the formation you asked. ( later i will add more functionality and filter )

At the moment, this is working with this line as an objective :

```
model.Maximize(sum([card.calculate_rating(position, coefficients, 0) * card_vars[(card, position)]
for card in roster for position in max_player_positions]))
```

Card is a class Card imported from database, and contains all attributes and statistics of a player.
Roster is just the collection of these cards.
max_player_positions is just the number of position needed for a certain formation

card_vars is a dict of boolean (card,position) which keep if a player is selected or not in the simulated team.

calculate_rating(position, coefficient) is a class card function which return the rating of the player at the selected position, calculated with his stats and the coefficients of this position I set in an other part of my app.

So the solver give me the best team by doing the maximise of the sum of all players selected into a single iteration.

Now I need to go deeper and it concerns the only variable i didn't explain : 0
This variable can be 0 - 1 - 2 or 3. It change the statistic of the card depending of this level. At 0 it just keep basic stats of the player.

The way it changes depend of the amount of others players sharing the same club / nation or championship and being placed at their best position.

And this is where I'm totally lost, because everything I could try resolve on the same problem. How can I get the amount of players of the same club/nation or championship currently selected when an other card is "simulated" into a team ?

I tried some approach like creating an other boolean variable like this :

```
club_vars = {}
for card in roster:
    for position in max_player_positions:
        if position in positions:
            club_vars[card.name, card.club] = model.NewBoolVar(f"{card.club}_{card.name}_{card.position}")
```

My hope was to get a YES or NO if a player of a certain club is selected, but again i'm stuck because even with that I don't find the logic to keep the number of same nation / same club etc.

I started an other approach by creating a boolean to have every possible YES or NO for every possibility of "Same player of a club == " 1 /2 /3 /4 .... 11 and combine that with an other dict ...

```
for club in club_vars.keys():
    for nb in nb_players_possible_chem:
        count_club_vars[(club[1], nb)] = model.NewBoolVar(f"{club[1]}_{nb}")
    name_club = club[1]
    count_club[name_club] = 0
```

but ....again .... I can't keep the number and adding constraint even with OnlyEnforceIf will just test conditions, I didn't find yet a way to make it working.

I think I reached my limit in term of understanding what can be do. So I might take any hints to know in which direction I could search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can refer to my repo (https://github.com/Regista6/FIFA-23-Automated-SBC-Solving) to calculate chemistry which I think what you are trying to do.

Comment: wow crazy project, will have me save some time this year if I knew it exist ahah
I added an answer to my post based on Laurent's answer, might give a test tonight. By the way, if you are up to participate in my project feel free to reach me out

Comment: Are you trying to model how the internal stats of players change with chemistry?.

Comment: Yes exactly, but this is where I cant find a clear solution yet

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of features of the feature (nation, league, club)
Given a set of players, each one with a Boolean var if the player is selected and in a valid position:

card[nation] = sum(players of this nation) where card[nation] is an int_var.  To compute the bonus, use this [doc page for inspiration](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md).

have 4 Boolean variables b0, b1, b2, b3 for the bonus part of this nation.

then

b0 implies card <= 2
b1 implies card in [3..4]  # I forgot the exact threshold
b2 implies card in [5..7]
b3 implies card >= 8

Do the same for league and clubs

Then for each non icon, non hero player. chemistry = b1 + b2 * 2 + b3 * 3  + league bonuses + club bonuses...

Comment: This is exactly how I [implemented](https://github.com/Regista6/FIFA-23-Automated-SBC-Solving/blob/edcfc5747a981148e1c6a0c130175b0c084bdf1a/optimize.py#L229) chemistry!

Answer (score -1):

thanks @laurent

Based on the club_vars I previously describe and your answer.

Does it make sense for you :

```
for club in club_vars.keys():
count_club[club[1]] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, "count_club[f"{club[1]}"]")
count_club[club[1]] = sum(club_vars[card.name, card.club) for card in roster)

b_club0 = model.NewBoolVar('b_club0')
b_club1 = model.NewBoolVar('b_club1')
b_club2 = model.NewBoolVar('b_club2')
b_club3 = model.NewBoolVar('b_club3')

for club in club_vars.keys():
model.Add(count_club[club[1]]<2).OnlyEnforceIf(b_club0)
model.Add(2 <= count_club[club[1]] < 4).OnlyEnforceIf(b_club1)
model.Add(4 <= count_club[club[1]] < 7).OnlyEnforceIf(b_club2)
model.Add(7 <= count_club[club[1]]).OnlyEnforceIf(b_club3)

for card in roster:
chemistry_club = b_club0 + b_club1 + b_club2 * 2 + b_club3 * 3
chemistry = chemistry_club + .... chemistry_nation + chemistry_championship

If chemistry > 3:
chemistry = 3

model.Maximize(sum([card.calculate_rating(position, coefficients, chemistry) * card_vars[(card, position)]
for card in roster for position in max_player_positions]))
```

### Comments inline:

- You cannot write `model.Add(3 <= expr < 6)`. You need to write `model.AddLinearConstraint(expr, 3, 5)`.
- if chemistry > 0 chemistry = 3. This is invalid. You need to use a min equality. `model.AddMinEquality(chemistry, [3, b0 + b1 ...])`
- Reread the doc page. You must use Boolean variables or their negation in the OnlyEnforceIf() part.

Edit : the correct logic might be

```
for card in roster:
model.Add(b_club0).OnlyEnforceIf(count_club[club[card.club]]<2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).